# Makefile error message: make[1]: *** [aclocal.m4] Fehler 127

Tags: makefile, autotools

I try to use the "make"-command, but it shows the following error message:

```
cd .. && make  am--refresh
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/media/user/8d6aed42-01a5-4f03-840b-ed57a8d077a3/ubuntu_temp_packet/empathy-3.8.6« wird betreten
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /media/user/8d6aed42-01a5-4f03-840b-ed57a8d077a3/ubuntu/temp_packet/empathy-3.8.6/missing aclocal-1.13 -I m4 
/media/user/8d6aed42-01a5-4f03-840b-ed57a8d077a3/ubuntu/temp_packet/empathy-3.8.6/missing: Zeile 81: aclocal-1.13: Befehl nicht gefunden
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.13' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make[1]: *** [aclocal.m4] Fehler 127
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/media/user/8d6aed42-01a5-4f03-840b-ed57a8d077a3/ubuntu/temp_packet/empathy-3.8.6« wird verlassen
make: *** [../aclocal.m4] Fehler 2
```

After a google search I recognized that a lot of people faced the same problem, but none of them really solved it.

If I run the make in debug mode I get the following output:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dies ist Freie Software; siehe die Programmquellen für Vervielfältigungsbedingungen.
 Es gibt KEINE Gewährleistung; nicht einmal für VERMARKTUNG oder NUTZBARKEIT FÜR EINEN
 BESONDEREN ZWECK.

Dieses Programm wurde erstellt für i686-pc-linux-gnu
»make«-Steuerdateien werden gelesen …
»make«-Steuerdatei »Makefile« wird gelesen...
»make«-Steuerdateien werden aktualisiert …
 Betrachte Target-Datei »Makefile«.
   Betrachte Target-Datei »Makefile.in«.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »Makefile.am«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »Makefile.am«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »Makefile.am«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »Makefile.am,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »Makefile.am«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »RCS/Makefile.am,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »Makefile.am«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »RCS/Makefile.am«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »Makefile.am«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »s.Makefile.am«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »Makefile.am«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »SCCS/s.Makefile.am«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »Makefile.am« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »Makefile.am«.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »Makefile.am« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/as-compiler-flag.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.as-compiler-flag.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ax_config_dir.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.ax_config_dir.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/empathy-args.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/empathy-args.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/empathy-args.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-args.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.empathy-args.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/empathy-args.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/empathy-args.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/empathy-args.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/empathy-args.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/empathy-valgrind.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.empathy-valgrind.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/gsettings.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/gsettings.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/gsettings.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »gsettings.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.gsettings.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/gsettings.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/gsettings.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/gsettings.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/gsettings.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/intltool.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/intltool.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »intltool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/intltool.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »intltool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/intltool.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »intltool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/intltool.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »intltool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.intltool.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »intltool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.intltool.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/intltool.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/intltool.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/intltool.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/intltool.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/libtool.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/libtool.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »libtool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/libtool.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »libtool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/libtool.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »libtool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/libtool.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »libtool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.libtool.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »libtool.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.libtool.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/libtool.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/libtool.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/libtool.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/libtool.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/ltoptions.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/ltoptions.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ltoptions.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltoptions.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.ltoptions.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/ltoptions.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/ltoptions.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/ltoptions.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/ltoptions.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/ltsugar.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/ltsugar.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ltsugar.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltsugar.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.ltsugar.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/ltsugar.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/ltsugar.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/ltsugar.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/ltsugar.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/ltversion.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/ltversion.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ltversion.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »ltversion.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.ltversion.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/ltversion.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/ltversion.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/ltversion.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/ltversion.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/lt~obsolete.m4,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/RCS/lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/s.lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../m4/SCCS/s.lt~obsolete.m4«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4«.
     Kein Befehl für »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../configure.ac«.
      Suche nach einer impliziten Regel für »../configure.ac«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »configure.ac«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../configure.ac,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »configure.ac«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../RCS/configure.ac,v«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »configure.ac«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../RCS/configure.ac«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »configure.ac«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../s.configure.ac«.
      Versuche Muster-Regel mit Ersetzung »configure.ac«.
      Versuche implizite Voraussetzung »../SCCS/s.configure.ac«.
      Keine implizite Regel für »../configure.ac« gefunden.
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../configure.ac«.
     Kein Befehl für »../configure.ac« und keine Voraussetzung 
wurde tatsächlich verändert.
     Es ist nicht notwendig, das Target »../configure.ac« neu zu erzeugen.
     Betrachte Target-Datei »../aclocal.m4«.
       Die Datei »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/empathy-args.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/gsettings.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/intltool.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/libtool.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/ltoptions.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/ltsugar.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/ltversion.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
       Die Datei »../configure.ac« wird "gestutzt" (der Abhängigkeitsgraph).
      Fertig mit den Voraussetzungen für die Ziel-Datei »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/as-compiler-flag.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/ax_config_dir.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/empathy-args.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/empathy-valgrind.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/gsettings.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/intltool.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/libtool.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/ltoptions.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/ltsugar.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/ltversion.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../m4/lt~obsolete.m4« ist älter als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
      Die Datei »../configure.ac« ist jünger als das davon abhängige Ziel »../aclocal.m4«.
     Das Target »../aclocal.m4« muss neu erzeugt werden.
cd .. && make  am--refresh
Nehme Kindprozess 0x089c3bd0 (../aclocal.m4) PID 10174 in die Kette auf.
Aktiver Kindprozess 0x089c3bd0 (../aclocal.m4) PID 10174 
...
```

What is the root cause of this issue and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I am not good with Deutch, but the main error is `Befehl nicht gefunden` (`Command not found`) and "Warning" below explained what is going wrong: You need `aclocal` program for process given make target (`am-refresh`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configure/Makefile.in was created with an aclocal binary called aclocal-1.13. You either don't have it installed, or yours is called different.

Make sure that you have autoconf/automake installed and then call "autoreconf" to regenerate Makefile.in & Co.